# Jasper Report Showing Up Blank Sometimes

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an application that utilizes Jasper Reports 3.7.6, mainly for backwards-compatibility with the app's predecessor (i.e., the previous app was primarily used to generate sale certificates but the current app is mainly used to generate e-mails to convey the same information).

My QA person has just pointed out that the certificate-generation functionality only shows him a blank web page when run in his environment, and that is also the case for our development-build environment. But when I run the app on my local machine, I get the PDF file displayed as expected. Having not looked at this functionality in a while, and having never been that familiar with Jasper Reports (this was developed by another programmer who left the company years ago), I'm at a loss as to how to resolve what seems like an intermittent issue.

Here's the code that uses Jasper to generate the sales certificate:

```
    // filePath verified as set to executable's directory
    String fileName = filePath + "/Certificate.jasper";
    String outFileName = "Certificate" + certObject.getSerial() + ".pdf";


    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    try 
    {
        if(certObject != null)
        {
            ArrayList<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList();
            certList.add(certObject);

            // Create the print object
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, hm, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( (ArrayList) certList , true));

            // Create a PDF exporter
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

            // Set the output file name in the HTTP response                            
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", 
                                    "attachment; filename=" + outFileName);  

            // Set the print object of the exporter, and set its
            // output stream to be that of the HTTP response object
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);                
            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outStream);

            // Export the PDF file                
            exporter.exportReport();
        }

    } catch (JRException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("JRException: "+e.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException: "+ioe.toString());
    }
```

I should also note that, if memory and subVersion logs serve, this functionality previously wrote the certificate PDF out to the executable's directory then opened that file in a browser window. I can't remember why I changed the functionality, except possibly for efficiency (i.e., not filling up that directory with lots of PDFs). Do I need to switch back to doing things that way? I really don't want to invest too much effort into what is not likely to be used much in the new application, so if anyone can give me a simple solution that will work consistently, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your servlet to accept GET or change to Chrome.

I had the same trouble with IE, when the user clicks the generate PDF button IE makes a POST to the Java method, but right when the servlet responds with the PDF output, the Acrobat Plugin is loaded, which makes a second post but this time is a GET, and my controller didn't respond to GET submits.

Comment: This issue seems to be related more to the server than the browser, since it doesn't seem to matter which browser is used, but it does matter what server the app is running on.